# set div at bottom of page without overlapping another div at smaller screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I would like to vertically align 2 divs - a footer div at the bottom of my page (about 15px margin from the bottom), and a content div in the center of the page).  The webpage will be responsive. Her is the jsfiddle of the page: 
https://jsfiddle.net/tyvodoh0/1/

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class='center'>
        <div id='content'>
            <div id='profile_pic'>
                <img src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'/>
            </div>
            <div id='information'>
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <h2>Subtitle</h2>
                        <p> 4
down vote
favorite


Does the position of the sun in a hollow earth scenario affect the way light scattering would "color" the sky?

My understanding is the reddish-orange color during sunrise/sunset is caused by the sun being at a more oblique angle in contrast to the standard blue when the sun is fully up.

My intuition states that the sky's color wouldn't change much, or if it did would become a washed out version of whatever it normally would be, ie blue on Earth. The most dramatic coloring that I could imagine would be a gradient from say blue to red as you look from the center of the sky to the horizon, given an Earth colored sun and atmosphere. I doubt the gradient scenario is possible, but it would be neat if it was.
</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='footer'>
        <p>
        Div to be set at bottom
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 /* css */

    h1 {
    color: #3a2a0c;
    font-size: 47px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

h2 {
    color: #3a2a0c;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

h3 {
    color: #926d55;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

p {
    color: #3a2a0c;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 110%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #caccc6;
}

hr {
    border-color: #3edf4f6;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.center {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: pink;
    float: none;
}

#content {
     margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: 1235px;
    background: red;
}

#profile_pic {
    width: 396px;
    padding-right: 33px;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
}

#profile_pic img {
  width: 396px;
  height: auto;
  }
}

#information {
    width: 806px;
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
}

#contact {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #926d55;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

#contact span {
    margin-right:22px;
}

#information p {
    padding: 40px 0;
}

#left {
    float: left;
}

#right {
    float: right;
}

.links {
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.links img {
    margin-right: 6px;
}

.links a {
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    color: #3a2a0c;
}

.links a:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.links a:hover {
    color: #926d55;
}

.footer {
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code to make it responsive. You can work further to fix the position of the image when the window is resize.

```css
h1 {
 color: #3a2a0c;
 font-size: 47px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-bottom: 14px;
}

h2 {
 color: #3a2a0c;
 font-size: 28px;
 text-transform: capitalize;
 margin-bottom: 14px;
}

h3 {
 color: #926d55;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}

p {
 color: #3a2a0c;
 font-size: 15px;
 text-align: justify;
 line-height: 110%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #caccc6;
}

hr {
 border-color: #3edf4f6;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.center {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
 background: pink;
 float: none;
}

#content {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%; 
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
}

#profile_pic {
 width: 396px;
 padding-right: 33px;
 float: left;
 background: blue;
}

#profile_pic img {
  width: 396px;
  height: auto;
}

/*            
#information {
width: 806px;
 background: yellow;
 float: left;
}
*/            

#contact {
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #926d55;
}

.hide {
 display: none;
}

#contact span {
 margin-right:22px;
}

#information p {
 padding: 40px 0;
}

#left {
 float: left;
}

#right {
 float: right;
}

.links {
 padding-top: 15px;
 font-size: 15px;
}

.links img {
 margin-right: 6px;
}

.links a {
 margin-left: 6px;
 margin-right: 6px;
 color: #3a2a0c;
}

.links a:last-child {
 margin-right: 0px;
}

.links a:hover {
 color: #926d55;
}

.footer {
 float: none;
 top: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='center'>
        <div id='content'>
            <div id='profile_pic'>
                <img src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'/>
            </div>
            <div id='information'>
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <h2>Subtitle</h2>
                <p> 4
down vote
favorite

Does the position of the sun in a hollow earth scenario affect the way light scattering would "color" the sky?

My understanding is the reddish-orange color during sunrise/sunset is caused by the sun being at a more oblique angle in contrast to the standard blue when the sun is fully up.

My intuition states that the sky's color wouldn't change much, or if it did would become a washed out version of whatever it normally would be, ie blue on Earth. The most dramatic coloring that I could imagine would be a gradient from say blue to red as you look from the center of the sky to the horizon, given an Earth colored sun and atmosphere. I doubt the gradient scenario is possible, but it would be neat if it was.
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='footer'>
            <p>Div to be set at bottom</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The height of the `.wrapper` is set to: `height:100%`, you can remove it if you do not need it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you want the wrapper div to cover the 100% of the height and the width of the page, and in order to set the footer at the bottom of the page you need to change the footer class to

```
.footer {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

This will allow the div to stay at the bottom with a margin of 15 px.